# Standard Status Code for One Time Password(OTP) Verification API

Tags: node.js, rest

I am using below `status codes` for Verification API. Are they correct? If not what should be standard status codes for below scenarios.

- OTP validation Successful(200)
- OTP is not verified(401)
- OTP is Expired(410)
- OTP resend limit exceeded(429)
- OTP is invalid(409)
- OTP is already verified(409)

Comment: what does otp mean?

Comment: one time password

Comment: one time password. Edited in question now.

Answer (score 4):

`OTP lifie cycle ::`

`ACTIVE` – The OTP is still active

`VERIFIED` – The OTP was verified successfully

`EXPIRED` – The OTP expired

`TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS` – The OTP validation requests exceeded the maximum allowed
by the application configuration

`OTP status code ::`

1. `202` Accepted  => OTP validation Successful
2. `403` Forbidden => which will return once all of the allowed attempts are reached to verify the code and were all unsuccessful (three by default) or the OTP code has expired (after five minutes, by default)
3. `410` Gone => Once an OTP reaches a final state (verified, expired or failed after too many attempts), the API always returns HTTP response code "410 Gone"
4. `401` => OTP is not valid ( Unauthorized ).

Comment: what is the source of this?